# Code alterations to support python2.x and beautifulsoup3.x

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to alter the following code so as t run it on python2.x and beautifulsoup3.x

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()

pages = []

req = session.get('webpage')

content = req.content.split("</html>")


for page in content[:-1]:
    doc = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page)

    name = doc.find('table', id='table2').find('table').findAll('td')[3].text
    print name

    tables = doc.findAll('table', id="conn")
    target_table = None
    for table in tables:
        try:
            title = table.find('thead').find('td').text
        except:
            title = None
        if title == 'ESME  DETAILS':
            target_table = table
            break
    if target_table:
        esme_trs = target_table.find('tbody').findAll('tr')
        for tr in esme_trs:
            print "\t", tr.find('td').text
```

Comment: What about the code segment doesn't work in Py2.x an BS3.x ?

Comment: I get an error message that says it couldnt find the module for request so i run the same code in python3 and it couldnt find module for module for BS

Comment: @Christian Witts, was running in linux

Comment: @mata if i didnt, is there any possible way to install it? ive tried re-installing python but to no use. dont wanna mess with BS

Comment: @mata thanks. I just got requests installed in virtualenv and got the code to run. thanks.

Comment: @mata I think you deserve the credit for enlightening me on modules and libraries. you should probably post an answer so i could pick that.

Comment: @Selase - Thanks. I've converted my comments to an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `requests` is not installed in the python2.X installation, only for python3.X

`requests` isn't standard library so it doesnt't come installed with python, so you need to install it manually.

See the instructions are on the [requests website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) for how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up `requests`, either set your default Python installation to your Py2.x or install `requests` via the source code and instead of just running `python setup.py install` rather run `/path/to/python2.x setup.py install` to have it install to your 2.x instance.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I installed the Virtualenv and then installed both modules for Request and BS3.x and got the code to run as required.